# zoom buttons for iframe

Tags: iframe, zooming

I created iframe for my own map (it's a big image).
I need to create buttons for zoom-in and zoom-out on this image.
Can you help me, please.

I googled it, but couldn't find any clear answer for this.

I have this

```
<div class="scale_buttons">
  <button class="button button1" id="zoom-in">+</button>
  <button class="button button2" id="zoom-out">-</button>
</div>

<div class="map" id="map">

</div><!--map-->
```

Image is a bg. And I need to zoom it by click the buttons